# Spring method replacement for final methods

Tags: java, spring

I came across Method Replacer and want to know if we can use Method Replacer for Final methods.

Here is the code :

```
public class FriendlyImpl implements Friendly {
  public void sayHello(String name) {
    System.out.println("Hello "+ name);
  }
}
```

Here is the code for Method replacer :

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.support.MethodReplacer;

public class FriendlyReplacer implements MethodReplacer {
  public Object reimplement(Object o, Method m, Object[] a)
      throws Throwable {

    System.out.println("Hola "+a[0]);

    return null;
  }
}
```

Here is the bean.xml

```
<beans>
  <bean id="friendly"
  class="com.habuma.wiring.FriendlyImpl">
    <replaced-method name="sayHello" replacer="friendlyReplacer">
    <arg-type>String</arg-type>
</replaced-method>
  </bean>

 <bean id="friendlyReplacer"
  class="com.habuma.wiring.FriendlyReplacer"/>
</beans>
```

Answer (score 2):

Final methods cannot be override be injection/JSR-330.

Comment: Spring uses reflection to find the methods (even private methods). It should also be able to access those final methods. Still seeking for answer

Comment: can anybody comment on this?

Answer (score 1):

Ya you are write that Spring finds private method using reflection api, but in method replacer concept spring create a subclass of our target class i.e the class in which the method we want to replace resides and overrides this method with our provided replaced method in that spring generated subclass.
So, if the method is final if cannot override the method voilating java rules.